# PyCaret's new feature EDA failed to launch

Tags: python, eda

I just installed PyCaret 2.3.6 today on my Mac running Monterey 12.1. The installation went fine on Google CoLab and I used the heart_disease dataset and the usual initial setup instructions. All worked well until I tried eda(). Initially, I saw several plots but noted I could not change the Y axis variable. When I ran all kernels again, eda failed to launch and gave the following error message

Classifying variables in data set...
13 Predictors classified...
No variables removed since no ID or low-information variables found in data set

### ################ Binary_Classification VISUALIZATION Started #####################

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_353/3763129898.py in 
----> 1 eda()

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/autoviz/AutoViz_Holo.py in draw_cat_vars_hv(dfin, dep, nums, cats, chart_format, problem_type, mk_dir, verbose)
240
241     x = pnw.Select(name='X-Axis', value=quantileable[0], options=cats)
--> 242     y = pnw.Select(name='Y-Axis', value=quantileable[1], options=quantileable)
243
244     ## you need to decorate this function with depends to make the widgets change axes real time ##

IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Although not in the directions I read, adding "display_format='inline' to both the EDA command and dashboard command makes them post in the notebook and not externally